# Colon after first span inside label with CSS selectors

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors

With [::after CSS pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) I add colon after `<span>` in `<label>` with `.control-label` class from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal):

```css
label.control-label > span::after {
  content: ":"
}
```

```html
<label for="notRequiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Not required input</span>
</label>
```

But, when `<input>` is required I have to deal with this markup, with asterisk which I can not remove (at least for a while I can not modify it):

```html
<label for="requiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Required input</span> <span class="text-danger">*</span>
 </label>
```

And then I have additional colon also after asterisk. I tried:

```
label.control-label::first-child::after {
  content: ":"
}
```

But I ended up unexpected result: I had colon only after asterisk. Is there a way to put colon only after first span inside label? I include a snippet which covers my problem - thank you in advance for every help.

```css
label.control-label > span::after {
  content: ":"
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="notRequiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Not required input</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="notRequiredInput">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="requiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Required input</span> <span class="text-danger">*</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="requiredInput" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to put colon only after first span inside label?

This is the selector you need.

```
label.control-label span:first-child::after {
      content: ":"
    }
```

```css
label.control-label span:first-child::after {
  content: ":"
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="notRequiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Not required input</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="notRequiredInput">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="requiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Required input</span>  <span class="text-danger">*</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="requiredInput" required>
</div>
```

Comment: It's nice, but I need: `Required input: *`, colon before asterisk - maybe it's weird but if I want to get rid of colons hard-coded in HTML, I need to do it - case is I need colon after first span, no matter how many spans exists in label :)

Comment: Fixed it for you...but there's no reason to actually remove the colons from the HTML...there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It looks exactly like I have in mockups, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yeah, it's ok to have colons - but I have quite big forms and I often forget to add it, and my CEO isn't happy with that :) Of course one of the solutions is custom form element directive like `<my-text-field></my-text-field>` nwhich cares about all `form-group`, but within few days project goes into production and it is recognised as too risky.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put the colon on the `<label>` element?

```css
label.control-label::after {
  content: ":"
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="notRequiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Not required input</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="notRequiredInput">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="requiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Required input</span> <span class="text-danger">*</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="requiredInput" required>
</div>
```

Comment: It's fine, but unfortunately in mockups I have `Required input: *`, I need colon after first span, no matter how many spans exists in label.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use pseudo-class `:not`

```
label.control-label > span:not(.text-danger)::after {
  content: ":"
}
```

[JSFiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/r6tpctpd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
label.control-label > span::after {
  content: ":"
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="notRequiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Not required input</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="notRequiredInput">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="requiredInput" class="control-label">
    <span>Required input</span> <span class="text-danger">*</span>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="requiredInput" required>
</div>
```